# Problemas con jsPanel: $.jsPanel is not a function

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente jsPanel:

```
 var oPanel = $.jsPanel({
    contentAjax: {
        url: 'Vista/Calendario',
        done: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR, panel) {
            panel.content.append(data);    
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('Error:', textStatus, '-', errorThrown);
        }
    },
    id: 'panel-calendario',
    contentSize: {
        width: '80%',
        height: '90%'
    },
    position: { my: "center", at: "center", offsetY: 0, offsetX: 0 },
    panelType: 'modal',
    theme: 'bootstrap-primary',
    panelSize: {
        width: '80%',
        height: '90%'
    },
    headerControls: {
        minimize: 'remove',
        smallify: 'remove',
        normalize: 'remove',
        maximize: 'remove'
    },
    headerTitle: 'Calendario - Días No Hábiles',
});
oPanel.dragit('disable');
```

Anda todo muy bien, al hacer click en el botón que lo abre se abre de manera correcta. Ahora, cuando lo cierro e intento abrir de vuelta me dice Uncaught TypeError: $.jsPanel is not a function. Intenté cambiar el $ por jQuery y cerrar el panel directamente con oPanel.close() pero el error persiste. No sé qué hacer.

Comment: ya lo pude resolver! tenía scripts que se estaban pisando